# How to get the fifth field of the second register of a table?

Tags: mysql

I have an **automatically generated SQL database**.

I don't know the name of the fields, and I don't know the value of the fields; I just know which number of register I need to get and with number of field of that register.

For example, if I need to obtain the *fifth* field of the *second* register of the table "Table1" of the database, which SQL query should I do?

Comment: 'Register' is not a term used in the database world (unless you use DB2, and then it refers to an attribute of an SQL session, not to part of a table).  Are you intending to mean 'row'?

Comment: How are you accessing the MySQL database?  Which programming language are you using to access the database?  Are you using the `mysql_*()` functions, PDO, an abstraction library (if so, which one)?  The answer could depend on these questions.

Answer (score 1):

Rows in a table in a database are formally unordered, though they are, of course, stored in some order.  There's no way in SQL to refer to columns in a table by position; you must know the name of the column.

Since you know the table name, you can interrogate the system catalog to learn the columns in the table, and therefore the second column name in the table (assuming it isn't a single-column table).

However, if you don't know the schema of the tables, you can't do anything meaningful in the way of querying the data.  You have to know what the columns mean to know what the query is going to do.

Clearly you can run some query on the table (once you know the column name you're after) and then collect two rows of data; the second row is the one you're after.

...

There's a half-cheat that you can use which will work if your database access language returns you rows with the values for each row in an array - as in Perl with DBI, or PHP, or ...

```
SELECT * FROM Table1;
```

This will collect all the data (including column 5, assuming there are that many columns), and your `fetch` operation may return the values represented by `*` into an array, and you can then look at the value in the fifth element of the array for the second row to see the data. In many SQL DBMS (I don't know about MySQL specifically), you can even use an obsolescent notation to order by the fifth column:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY 5;
```

The 5 here refers to the fifth column in the result set which, given that this is selecting all columns from a single table, means the fifth column of the table.

However, running blind like that is a ridiculous proposition for the long term.  You must understand the schema and its interpretation to be able to use a database sensibly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEMA = '<DATABASENAME>' 
AND information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = '<TABLENAME>' 
ORDER BY information_schema.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION ASC
```

This would give you the table metadata, including column names and types.

Answer (score 0):

can you not do it thru PHP (or your choice):

```
$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
if ($i == 2)
{
   echo $row[4];
}

$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have access to the database?
Can't you do:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE Table1;
```

The order of the columns returned should give you the names of the fields which you can then use in a query.